# How does boost::dynamic_bitset store bits

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

I am having a hard time understanding what boost:::dynamic_bitset, or std::vector do internally. What I eventually want to do is compose a network frame and send it via socket, but I just cannot convert them in a way that keeps the bit order I assembled...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp"


int main()
{
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> b(8, 10);          // 8 Bits, value 10

    std::cout << "b     = " << b << std::endl; // as expected

    printf("Vector size: %i\n", b.size());
    printf("Bits: %d", b);                     // ?
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the class overloaded the << stream operator, therefore I have correct output, while printf seems to show the raw structure. Appears not even deterministic to me (below repeatedly executed the same .exe without recompiling):

[image: cmd]

My questions:

1. What happens basically under the hood? Apparently it is not at all
   comparable to an array.
2. How can I send such a bitset via socket
   send() ?

Comment: Passing an object which is not type `int` to `printf`'s `%d` specifier is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::dynamic_bitset<>` internally stores bits in unsigned integers, which are stored in a `std::vector<>`. The internal storage is not exposed though, so you cannot access it directly.

You can use [`to_block_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#to_block_range) to copy a `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` into an array of integers. And a [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#cons4) to convert that array of integers back to a `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`.

Comment: Quite some time passed, but thanks for the answer. However I  wanted to avoid a copy operation, so I reconsidered my whole approach and went back to C style bit operations on a char array.